# Contents of question X is dupe of old question Y, but X (only) has tag feature-request - close as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

See [this close vote review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/9593) on SO. The misunderstanding in/from the warning described in [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288261/misleading-warning-text-some-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-declined) has already been explained in [an older question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251335/why-do-i-get-a-declined-flags-warning-when-theres-only-one-thats-recent).

But the new question has an <kbd>feature-request</kbd> tag, and the old one does not.

Should the new one be closed as duplicate? I assume we don't want the *feature-request* to fall through the cracks.

I voted to leave it open.
Should it need to be closed, we would have to edit the older one to include the tag and add a request in the text, right?

Comment: I could have voted it the other way around... but I don't think a single tag difference should matter, despite one being a feature request